# datagridview binding source filter

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, bindingsource

I am trying to filter Data out of a BindingSource - but it doesnt work.
What am i doing wrong?
I have reduced my Code to a minimalistic example.

The Problem is, if i type something in the TextBox - nothing happens.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<myObj> myObjList= new List<myObj>();
        myObjList.Add(new myObj("LastNameA", "Peter"));
        myObjList.Add(new myObj("LastNameA", "Klaus"));
        myObjList.Add(new myObj("LastNameB", "Peter"));

        foreach (myObj obj in myObjList)
        {
            bs.Add(obj);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bs.Filter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }

}

public class myObj
{
    public myObj(string LastName, String Name)
    {
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Worked for me so far

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    BindingList<myObj> myObjList = new BindingList<myObj>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myObjList.Add(new myObj("LastNameA", "Peter"));
        myObjList.Add(new myObj("LastNameA", "Klaus"));
        myObjList.Add(new myObj("LastNameB", "Peter"));

        bs.DataSource = myObjList;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = myObjList;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingList<myObj> filtered = new BindingList<myObj>(myObjList.Where(obj => obj.Name.Contains(textBox1.Text)).ToList());

        dataGridView1.DataSource = filtered;
        dataGridView1.Update();
    }

}

public class myObj
{
    public myObj(string LastName, String Name)
    {
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter%28VS.90%29.aspx) says:

> Only underlying lists that implement the IBindingListView interface
>   support filtering.

Replace this

```
 List<myObj> myObjList= new List<myObj>();
```

with this

```
 BindingList<myObj> myObjList= new BindingList<myObj>();
```

Comment: I have read the MSDN documentation an now have applied the  BindingList. 
But if i typ letters in the TextBox - nothing happens

Comment: `BindingList<T>` doesn't implement `IBindingListView`.