# Sort dataGridView with comboBox

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

i've got a project: [image: dataGridView with some info]

I need comboBox to sort dataGridView, for example, I choose coupe and only 86 и Supra should be shown.

Also if I double click the needed car, another window will pop up [image: All available Camry sets]

I need this dataGridView2 to be sorted too.

So I've got 2 classes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Toyota_beta
{
    public class Models
    {

        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; } 
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }

        public List<Cars> Cars { get; set; }



        public Models(string model, string type, string year, 
        string price, List<Cars> cars)
        {
            Model = model; Year = year; Type = type;
            Price = price; Cars = cars;
        }
        public Models()
        {

            Cars = new List<Cars>();
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Toyota_beta
{
    public class Cars
    {

            public string Model { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public string Transmission { get; set; }
            public string Drive { get; set; }
            public int Hp { get; set; }
            public string Engine { get; set; }
            public int Price { get; set; }


            public Cars(string model, int year, string transmission, string drive, string engine,
            int hp, int price)
            {
                Model = model; Year = year; Transmission = transmission;
                Drive = drive; Hp = hp; Engine = engine; Price = price;
            }
            public Cars()
            { }

    }
}
```

And all the data in the dataGridView I inserted manually

```
namespace Toyota_beta
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<Models> listM = new List<Models>();
        public List<Cars> listC;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Yaris---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            listC = new List<Cars>();
            listC.Add(new Cars("Yaris L", 2020, "Manual", "FWD", "Fuel", 106, 15650));
            listC.Add(new Cars("Yaris XLE", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 106, 18750));

            listM.Add(new Models("Yaris ", "Sedan", "2020", "from 15,650$", listC));

            //Yaris Hatchback---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            listC = new List<Cars>();
            listC.Add(new Cars("Yaris LE Hatchback", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 106, 17750));


            listM.Add(new Models("Yaris Hatchback", "Hatchback", "2020", "from 17,750$", listC));

            //Corolla---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            listC = new List<Cars>();
            listC.Add(new Cars("Corolla L", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 139, 19600));
            listC.Add(new Cars("Corolla LE", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 139, 20050));
            listC.Add(new Cars("Corolla Hybrid LE", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 169, 23100));

            listM.Add(new Models("Cororlla", "Sedan", "2020", "from 19,600$", listC));
...
```

That's how I filled with data second dataGridView

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null || dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index == dataGridView1.RowCount - 1)
                return;

            Info formC = new Info();


            int n = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
            formC.carsBindingSource.DataSource = listM[n].Cars;

            formC.ShowDialog();
            modelsBindingSource.ResetCurrentItem();

        }
```

Maybe these pics can help you understand the general situation.

That's what I tried myself: creating a bool method that filters dataGridView to show only needed rows, but some problems are occurring.

```
private void b_Show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool select = false;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                if (TestRow(i))
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                    select = true;
                }
            }

        }
        private bool TestRow(int c)
        {
            Cars crs = Form1.listM[m];

            if (comboBox_type.Text != "" &&
                !crs.Type.Contains(comboBox_type.Text)) return false;





        }
```

I'm kinda new to c# so don't blame me too much pls for this crappy code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use the `BindingSource.Filter` property to achieve that. See the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/sort-and-filter-ado-net-data-with-wf-bindingsource-component). Also see the `BindingList` example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17317015/10216583).

Comment: Actually it doesn't answer all of my questions, thx anyway!